# CORS synchronous requests not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-domain, cors

The official documentation of jQuery ( [async ajax section](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) ) says that:

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation.

However this works in all recent browsers but firefox version >= 20. Here is the type of calls i'm making:

```
$.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      async: false,
      dataType : "text",
      url : link,
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },

      success: function(response){
         console.log("success ");
      },
        error: function(error){
            console.error(error);               
        }  
});
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening ?

**UPDATE:**
Ive tested both with jQuery and vanilla XHR the error is always the same

> [Exception... "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the
>   underlying object" code: "15" nsresult: "0x8053000f
>   (InvalidAccessError)"

Comment: You're not using dataType: "jsonp", so it must be the cross domain part, but you haven't showed us from where/to where this request is being made.

Comment: What does happen in FF? What does the network inspector tell you?

Comment: @tandrewnichols Im using CORS in order to make cross-domain requests.

Comment: @Bergi in the network inspector tab its not showing any request.

Comment: I need to have synchronous requests while using CORS, if i remove async:false the request is made with success.

Comment: And in the error console? What message is logged? Or does not happen anything?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `beforeSend` instead of `xhrField`.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType : "text",
    url : link,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log("success ");
    },
    error: function(error){
      console.error(error);               
    }
});
```