# Evil Firefox Error -- "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cors

I'm trying to figure out what is going on here. I've been at it for hours now and can't seem to get a grip on why this is happening.

I'm making a few AJAX calls, and I keep getting this error back only in Firefox (version 21) on Mac OS X.

Here is the error:

```
 "[Exception... "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object" 
   code: "15" nsresult: "0x8053000f (InvalidAccessError)"  location: 
   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js Line: 6"
```

I'm making a CORS call, so I set up my AJAX like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }

    });
```

And continue calls henceforth. Basically, does anyone out there have ANY experience with this error? I see some posts online but they all seem to do with Cross-Domain CSS, which I'm not using.

Comment: So you've tested on other browsers/OS's? And they all work?

Comment: Yes. All other browsers (including Firefox on Windows) work. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: In addition, it freezes and crashes the entire browser (but I think that's because it's happening multiple times)

Comment: Can you use unminified version and give exact line number?  Did you do any debugging?

Comment: @danronmoon I just tried the unminifed version, and the error happens in jquery on line 7717. It's difficult to debug as when it errors it crashes my entire browser.

Comment: From that line number I guess you're using jQuery 2? Have you tried 1.9.1? If it works there, you should report it as a bug (with cut-down example code)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything else in `xhrFields`? And `withCredentials` is certainly spelt correctly? The error message and line number means that something in `xhrFields` isn't a property that can be set on an `XMLHttpRequest` object…

Comment: @Dave I am using jQuery 2. I haven't tested in 1.9.1 but I will. I've copy and pasted the exact code above, so if everything is spelled right there (I think it is) I don't think it should do that. Do you know of any documentation that talks of this?

Comment: @streetlight Did you place breakpoint on line 7717 and find out what is being set on the XHR object before it errors?

Comment: @Dave I've now tested it in 2.0.0, 1.9.1 and 1.7.2, and I'm getting the same error (different lines of course). What's bizarre is that only SOME of my cross-domain calls are failing, not all of them. @ danronmoon I am testing that now!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Okay, so after of hours of testing (and great discussion from @Dave and @danronmoon, I've finally figured out what's going on.

The CORS (Cross-Domain Resource Sharing) calls I was making were set to 'async: false' -- (which I realize I did not include in my original post, as I thought it was inconsequential) this, seems to operate fine in all browsers except Firefox, where jQuery will bark at you and your ajax call will fail.

Thank you all for your help and I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thank you so much!! This problem was driving me nuts for the past couple days. I can cross this off my list now!

Comment: @EvanM no problem! I'm glad this helped someone else!

Comment: Thanks a million. Was struggling with this for some time now.

Comment: Ok so what if i want to use the async:false? Why is there an issue with FF with this? Has anyone found a workaround where async needs to be set to false?

Comment: It's not really an issue with FF -- it's a CORS issue, and FF seems to be the only one strictly enforcing it. All CORS calls must be async (at least in my research).

Comment: @streetlight it rather seems to be an async=false issue as I am facing the precise same issue.

Comment: I didn't understand why I had that mistake. I did not ask the question on that subject, but this answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is the first duckduckgo result for `InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object` I will add another source for this.

If you deal with such error when doing iframe/window actions, then you're probably prevented by the iframe's `sandbox` attribute (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox ) even when being on the same origin.

In my case, an `iframe` was trying to do a `window.top.location.href = ...` after a form submission success. The `allow-top-navigation` sandbox option is mandatory to do so. 
Funny thing, this sandbox option is *not* mandatory to *reload* the top browsing context... it's only required for navigating in it.

Comment: Or your resource have applied the sandbox attribute in the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

Comment: I added another answer for a more specific case of this, where the failure can still happen intermittently if the more restrictive `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation` option is set instead and async work (e.g. AJAX) is done in response to the user interaction.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I was using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) and called [`WebSocket.close(1001)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close). It doesn't like my [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#Status_codes). Changing it to `1000` or not specifying a code (default `1005`) works just fine.

Comment: See list of CloseEvent codes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent/code (in particular, note: `0–999 Reserved and not used`.)

Answer (score 2):

this is the real solution by Diogo Cardoso, the xhr object or parent seems to lack a toString() method

[CORS synchronous requests not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668386/cors-synchronous-requests-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: I see the issue you point out with FF's initial, but it remains best practice (and within the CORS specification) to make all CORS async - I believe this (or similar) issues will continue to crop up if programmers continue to go against the CORS specification. Thank you for adding to the conversation, btw!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a CORS problem caused by using ajax. But as user320550 asks, what if you NEED to use the property 'async:false'? I found that using the 'withCredentials:false' property as a workaround fixes the issue on firefox and doesn't affect other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add a somewhat nasty intermittent variant of Xenos's answer. As he mentioned, you can get this problem if you try and navigate the window by setting `window.top.location.href = ...` from within a sandboxed iframe, and that this can be prevented if your iframe has the `allow-top-navigation` option set.

But you might also find your iframe has the more restrictive `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation` [option](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-top-level-navigation-with-user-activation-browsing-context-flag). This will allow navigation, but only in response to a user action such as clicking a link or a button. For example, it will be allowed within a form submit event handler, but you can't just trigger it at an arbitrary point in time, such as from a setTimeout() callback with a long delay.

This can be problematic if you are (for example) using AJAX form submission before performing a redirect. The browser needs to decide if the navigation is in response to a user action or not. It does this by only allowing the navigation if it is considered to have happened within an *acceptable* time period of the user interaction. The HTML standard refers to this as [transient activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#transient-activation).

The bottom line is that if your AJAX call is *too slow*, or if your user has a poor network connection, the navigation will fail. How slow is too slow? I have only tested Firefox, but it appears to allow 5 seconds before it considers the user interaction to have expired.

Possible solutions:

- Ask whoever is responsible for the iframe options to upgrade to the blanket `allow-top-navigation` option
- Don't perform async work such as AJAX requests in between user actions and top navigation. For example, use old-school POST form submission directly to the back-end, rather than using an AJAX request
- Make sure your responses are as fast as possible. Catch any errors, and prompt the user to click something to trigger the navigation manually. For example:

```js
async function submitForm() {
    await doPotentiallySlowAsyncFormSubmit()
    try {
        window.top.location.href = ...
    } catch (e) {
        // Show message to user, e.g. "Form submitted, click here to go to the next step"
    }
}
```