# CORS not working with withCredentials=true sync ajax call on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, synchronization, cross-domain

I am trying to make a cross domain ajax sync call with withCredentials=true, i am not getting any error, the browser just got stuck. My chrome version is  40.0.2214.115 m.

I also tried same with latest version (35.0) of firefox and facing same issue " Invalid access error a parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object".

What could be the possible reason, any input would be helpful.

Comment: This is not enough information to reproduce the error. Add an example code!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evil Firefox Error -- "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677893/evil-firefox-error-a-parameter-or-an-operation-is-not-supported-by-the-under)

Comment: Btw. if I remember well this error is typical when you set XHR to sync mode and try to use async code, like xhr.onreadystatechange, etc...